aiohttp session request fail
I try to get data from Jira API with aiohttp session request and it's failed with 401.
Yes the problem is providing login and password (not token), but its work with requests.
This work:
r = requests.get(jira_full_url, auth=(login, password))
assert r.status_code == 200

HTTPX work as well:
async with AsynClient(jira_root_url) as session:
    resp = await session.get(relativ_url, auth=(login, password))
    assert resp.status_code == 200

And this fail:
async with ClientSession(jira_root_url, auth=BasicAuth(login, password)) as session:
    async with session.get(relativ_url) as resp:   # I try to set auth here too
        assert resp.status == 200                  # Here I got 401


The issue is that in aiohttp, the auth=BasicAuth() parameter does not automatically combine the base URL (jira_root_url) with the relative URL (relativ_url). You need to construct the full URL manually.

I don't think the auth parameter should have any effect on how a relative URL is treated. Please open an issue if that's the case.

Thanks everyone. For now I switch to HTPX.
I'll try to dig deeper. With BasicAuth Jira ask me to send username.
Later collect more info and open issue as @SamBull says.

i think you should to you auth in session.get request
async with session.get(relativ_url, auth=auth) as resp:

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
